# Import module into xquery with apache camel transformer EIP

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a camel route which is pretty simple, except for the used xquery which is why I extracted it into a separate file. In my camel route I call the xquery with the Transformer EIP:

```
.transform().xquery("resource:classpath:xquery/myCoolXQuery.xquery",String.class)
```

The XQuery itself works fine, but because of some functional changes I now want to import another XQuery module which I want to use as a "library" with some helping functions, because I have lots of XQuery-Files which could use them.

So what I did in my XQuery is:

```
xquery version "3.0" encoding "UTF-8";

declare namespace fn = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions';

(: Library of really helpful functions :)
import module namespace lib = "http://handofnod.com/xquery-lib" at "classpath:xquery/lib.xquery";
```

### Question:

How can I configure Apache Camel that the `StandardModuleURIResolver` is able to load the imported module from the *classpath*?

### So far investigations/ the problem

Unfortunately apache camel now throws a `NullpointerException` in the `StandardModuleURIResolver` at:

```
if ("classpath".equals(absoluteURI.getScheme())) {
    String path = absoluteURI.getPath();
    is = this.config.getDynamicLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

That's because the `absoluteURI` (which is `"classpath:xquery/lib.xquery"`) cannot be converted correctly and the variable `path` is `NULL` (that's pretty much code smell but not my business now).

The `absoluteURI` cannot be converted because the `net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser` has no value set in the `this.env.getStaticBaseURI()`.

So I tried during debugging to set the `staticBaseURI` value to `classpath` but then the `StandardModuleURIResolver` also returns an `absoluteURI` which has a `NULL` value in the `getPath()` thus resulting in the same `NullPointerException`.

So now I don't have any clue how to use the **Transformer-EIP** with an XQuery which uses a *module import* for some helper functions.

### Another possible solution

Another possible solution would be to not use the Transformer-EIP implemented in Apache Camel but instead use the `ToDefinition` because there it is possible to define a custom *Saxon Configuration* over an URL parameter which can use an overwritten `ModuleURIResolver` which then hasn't the problem.

Also, sure I could use a custom `Processor` implementation to achieve what I want, but that's not the point in using Camel which provides implementation for EIPs.

It would be great if I could use the **Transformer-EIP** with module import in my XQuery.

### Project setup is:

- Spring-Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE
- Apache Camel 2.22.2
- Build with Maven

### Final question

Can anyone help me pls?

### Edit 1:

I downloaded the sources from Camel and Saxon to be able to debug with more understanding what happens and tried some things:

First I tried to use an absolute path:

```
.transform().xquery("resource:classpath:/xquery/myCoolXQuery.xquery",String.class)
```

This way I don't get the `NullPointerException` anymore because in the `StandardModuleURIResolver` at `getQuerySource` the path is not `NULL` anymore:

Unfortunately the file cannot be loaded by 
`config.getDynamicLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);` and returns `NULL`.

So I thought I move the xquery files from the directory directly under `src\main\resoures` but that also didn't help and I had the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems there is no answer to my question I debugged further and further and it really just seems impossible to configure the Transformer-EIP with XQuery in any way. Also I was not able to find any way to load the imported xquery module from the classpath so I changed my code and now I call my xquery via the XQueryEndpoint which provides support for custom configuration:

`.to("xquery:/xquery/myCoolXQuery.xquery?configuration=#saxonConfig&resultsFormat=String")`

This way my route works. But it would have been nice to be able to use the `transform()` because the code would be easier to understand.